# GAWK - Finding a corresponding Action

Tags: gawk

I have a large file of sequentiually added lines of data that relate to parcels going through a system, this file is added to as each action takes place and builds throughout the day.  What I need to do it check the file say every minute and check for items that have not yet made it to there chute i.e. do not have an "DISCHARGE_VERIFIED".  The example below is one complete record but this could be spread throughout the file as thousands of items are processed at the same time.

```
170209 043314 0887 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<ITEM_AT_INDUCTION>, *********************, itemId=<12562305>, globalId=<12562305>, cmcIndex=<750>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: ProjectIdle>, inductionId=<3: IU04>, position=<sorter#0.induction#3: IU04>, itemRevisionNumber=<0> ##[
170209 043314 0888 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<SET_ITEM_ID>, ***************************, itemId=<12562305>, globalId=<12562305>, cmcIndex=<750>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: ProjectIdle>, itemRevisionNumber=<0> ##[
170209 043317 0314 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<SCANNER_RESULT>, ************************, itemId=<12562305>, globalId=<12562305>, cmcIndex=<750>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForData>, barcodeCount=<3>, barcodes=<[ProxyWrapperBarcode(barcode=<JJD014600004054211864>, type=<C0>, result=<OK>, ccType=<>), ProxyWrapperBarcode(barcode=<1910456693>, type=<A0>, result=<OK>, ccType=<>), ProxyWrapperBarcode(barcode=<2LAU2000+52000000>, type=<C0>, result=<OK>, ccType=<>)]>, codeSource=<ohscan>, scannerId=<4001: IU04-SCAN02>, scannerStatus=<0>, position=<sorter#0.scanner#4001: IU04-SCAN02>, itemRevisionNumber=<2> ##[
170209 043317 0315 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<DESTINATION_REQUEST>, *******************, itemId=<12562305>, globalId=<12562305>, cmcIndex=<750>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForData>, barcodes=<[ProxyWrapperBarcode(barcode=<JJD014600004054211864>, type=<C0>, result=<OK>, ccType=<>), ProxyWrapperBarcode(barcode=<1910456693>, type=<A0>, result=<OK>, ccType=<>), ProxyWrapperBarcode(barcode=<2LAU2000+52000000>, type=<C0>, result=<OK>, ccType=<>)]>, ccReason=<SCANNER_DATA_ADDED>, PreviousccResult=<>, sortSchemeId=<-1>, sortSchemeName=<>, logicalDestination=<>, BatchCountItem=<true>, collectionId=<-1>, goodsId=<>, position=<sorter#0.scanner#4001: IU04-SCAN02>, dynamicDataCount=<0>, dynamicData=<{}>, carrierId=<159>, carrierCount=<-1>, itemRevisionNumber=<2> ##[
170209 043317 0322 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<DESTINATION_REPLY>, *********************, itemId=<12562305>, globalId=<12562305>, cmcIndex=<750>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForDestination>, ccReason=<SCANNER_DATA_ADDED>, PendingccResult=<OK>, Pendingstrategy=<notSpecified>, PendingchuteGroup=<[3000]: Parked0>, PendingNotChutedestinationId=<-1>, PendingsortSchemeId=<-1>, PendingsortSchemeName=<>, PendinglogicalDestination=<>, PendinggoodsId=<>, PendingBatchCountItem=<true>, PendingcollectionId=<-1>, position=<sorter#0.scanner#4001: IU04-SCAN02>, dynamicDataCount=<0>, dynamicData=<{}>, itemRevisionNumber=<4> ##[
170209 043317 0322 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<REDIRECT_ITEM>, *************************, itemId=<12562305>, globalId=<12562305>, cmcIndex=<750>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForDestination>, PendingchuteGroup=<[3000]: Parked0>, Pendingstrategy=<notSpecified>, CscdestinationId=<-1: UnDef>, CmcdestinationId=<-1: UnDef>, position=<sorter#0.scanner#4001: IU04-SCAN02>, itemRevisionNumber=<4> ##[
170209 043317 0484 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<REDIRECT_ITEM_REPLY>, *******************, itemId=<12562305>, globalId=<12562305>, cmcIndex=<750>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForDestination>, CscdestinationId=<3000: Parked0>, chuteGroup=<[3000]: Parked0>, CmcdestinationId=<3000: Parked0>, position=<sorter#0.scanner#4001: IU04-SCAN02>, chuteListStartPoint=<-1>, itemRevisionNumber=<6> ##[
170209 043317 0486 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<RECONVERT>, *****************************, itemId=<12562305>, globalId=<12562305>, cmcIndex=<750>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForData>, CscdestinationId=<3000: Parked0>, chuteGroup=<[3000]: Parked0>, CmcdestinationId=<3000: Parked0>, position=<sorter#0.scanner#4001: IU04-SCAN02>, chuteListStartPoint=<-1>, itemRevisionNumber=<7> ##[
170209 043317 0486 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<DESTINATION_REQUEST>, *******************, itemId=<12562305>, globalId=<12562305>, cmcIndex=<750>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForData>, barcodes=<[ProxyWrapperBarcode(barcode=<JJD014600004054211864>, type=<C0>, result=<OK>, ccType=<>), ProxyWrapperBarcode(barcode=<1910456693>, type=<A0>, result=<OK>, ccType=<>), ProxyWrapperBarcode(barcode=<2LAU2000+52000000>, type=<C0>, result=<OK>, ccType=<>)]>, ccReason=<SCANNER_DATA_ADDED>, PreviousccResult=<OK>, sortSchemeId=<-1>, sortSchemeName=<>, logicalDestination=<>, BatchCountItem=<true>, collectionId=<-1>, goodsId=<>, position=<sorter#0.scanner#4001: IU04-SCAN02>, dynamicDataCount=<0>, dynamicData=<{}>, carrierId=<159>, carrierCount=<-1>, itemRevisionNumber=<7> ##[
170209 043317 0492 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<DESTINATION_REPLY>, *********************, itemId=<12562305>, globalId=<12562305>, cmcIndex=<750>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForDestination>, ccReason=<SCANNER_DATA_ADDED>, PendingccResult=<OK>, Pendingstrategy=<priority>, PendingchuteGroup=<[121]: FLY425>, PendingNotChutedestinationId=<-1>, PendingsortSchemeId=<-1>, PendingsortSchemeName=<>, PendinglogicalDestination=<FLY425>, PendinggoodsId=<>, PendingBatchCountItem=<true>, PendingcollectionId=<-1>, position=<sorter#0.scanner#4001: IU04-SCAN02>, dynamicDataCount=<0>, dynamicData=<{}>, itemRevisionNumber=<9> ##[
170209 043317 0492 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<REDIRECT_ITEM>, *************************, itemId=<12562305>, globalId=<12562305>, cmcIndex=<750>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForDestination>, PendingchuteGroup=<[121]: FLY425>, Pendingstrategy=<priority>, CscdestinationId=<3000: Parked0>, CmcdestinationId=<3000: Parked0>, position=<sorter#0.scanner#4001: IU04-SCAN02>, itemRevisionNumber=<9> ##[
170209 043317 0666 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<REDIRECT_ITEM_REPLY>, *******************, itemId=<12562305>, globalId=<12562305>, cmcIndex=<750>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForDestination>, CscdestinationId=<121: FLY425>, chuteGroup=<[121]: FLY425>, CmcdestinationId=<121: FLY425>, position=<sorter#0.scanner#4001: IU04-SCAN02>, chuteListStartPoint=<121>, itemRevisionNumber=<11> ##[
170209 043317 0667 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<ITEM_INDUCTED>, *************************, itemId=<12562305>, globalId=<12562305>, cmcIndex=<750>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: ProjectHeadingForChute>, inductionId=<3: IU04>, inductionMode=<SCANNER>, inductStatus=<NORMAL_ITEM>, carrierId=<159>, carrierCount=<1>, CmcdestinationId=<121: FLY425>, position=<sorter#0: MS01>, itemRevisionNumber=<12> ##[
170209 043327 0379 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<ITEM_DISCHARGED>, ***********************, itemId=<12562305>, globalId=<12562305>, cmcIndex=<750>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: ProjectHeadingForChute>, CscdestinationId=<121: FLY425>, chuteGroup=<[121]: FLY425>, CmcdestinationId=<121: FLY425>, ccResult=<OK>, sortSchemeId=<-1>, logicalDestination=<FLY425>, goodsId=<>, carrierId=<159>, length=<-1 mm>, width=<-1 mm>, height=<-1 mm>, volume=<-1 mm3>, position=<sorter#0.chute#121: FLY425>, itemRevisionNumber=<13> ##[
170209 043339 0765 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<DISCHARGE_VERIFIED>, ********************, itemId=<12562305>, globalId=<12562305>, cmcIndex=<750>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: ProjectWaitForVerification>, CscdestinationId=<121: FLY425>, chuteGroup=<[121]: FLY425>, CmcdestinationId=<121: FLY425>, position=<sorter#0.chute#121: FLY425>, itemRevisionNumber=<14> ##[
```

Once an item has made it to it's chute it is denoted as "DISCHARGE_VERIFIED" so I need to be able to pull out of the log file, the lines the that have an "itemId" but with no corresponding "DISCHARGE_VERIFIED" at that point in time and display the chute it is heading for which is held in the line "ITEM_INDUCTED", in the element "CmcdestinationId=<121: FLY425>" see below

```
170209 043317 0667 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<ITEM_INDUCTED>, *************************, itemId=<12562305>, globalId=<12562305>, cmcIndex=<750>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: ProjectHeadingForChute>, inductionId=<3: IU04>, inductionMode=<SCANNER>, inductStatus=<NORMAL_ITEM>, carrierId=<159>, carrierCount=<1>, CmcdestinationId=<121: FLY425>, position=<sorter#0: MS01>, itemRevisionNumber=<12> ##[
```

I'm doing this on a windows machine using gawk so have all the usual quotation issues.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Phil

Comment: where is your code sample?

Comment: valrog: I have a script which I can use to find the beginning and the end of an ITEMID

gawk "!first[$8] {first[$8] = $1 FS $2 FS} {last[$8] = $1 FS $2 FS} END { for (id in first) {print gensub(/itemId=<([^>]+)>,/, \"\\1\", \"g\", id) FS first[id] FS last[id]}}" Item.log | gawk -v OFS=, "{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}" > pt.log

But struggling to find out how to find find items which do not have a DISCHARGE_VERIFIED

Comment: `gawk` is just an implementation of `awk`. If you tag your questions with `awk` in addition to `gawk` you'll get vastly more people reading them and get multiple answers almost immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a working script. Save it as **inducted.awk** for example, so you skip all the windows quotation issues you describe.

inducted.awk:

```
/ITEM_INDUCTED/ {
    match($0, /itemId=<([^>]+)>/, ary1)
    match($0, /CmcdestinationId=<([^>]+)>/, ary2)
    dest[ary1[1]] = ary2[1]
}

/DISCHARGE_VERIFIED/ {
    match($0, /itemId=<([^>]+)>/, ary1)
    delete dest[ary1[1]]
}

END {
    for (id in dest) {
        print id " -- " dest[id]
    }
}
```

So basically, when a line with ITEM_INDUCTED is found, it adds the itemid and destination to an array.

And when a line has DISCHARGED_VERIFIED, that information is deleted from the array.

At the end of the script, remaining inducted but not discharged ids are printed with their destinations.

To execute it:

```
gawk -f .\inducted.awk large_log_file
```

if the awk file is not in the same folder as large_log_file, specify the full path for it.

Comment: Hi Valrog, appreciate you taking the time to have a look at this, I have ran it against the large file and get the following results : 
12575041 -- 4099: All Scanners
12575201 -- 0: !No Value!

Comment: Hi Val, thinking about it this is probably correct as a complete file would have all items INDUCTED and DISCHARGE so won't have any outstanding DISCHARGED events, I'll modify a text file and test against that, thanks again appreciate your time

Comment: I'm glad it helped

Comment: It really did, just an additional question is there a way to group the out put ? i.e. something like
CHU007 - 12
CHU012 - 123
FLY424 - 6

Comment: I'll post an additional question on the forum as well, but thanks for your help, rerally appreciate it